# Flash frame-rate is different in browser than it is in flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, frame-rate

I am using Flash CS4 and when testing my application my frame rate changes as it is programmed to do so. When I try to run the application in a browser (tried Firefox 4, Opera 10.5 and IE 8) the frame rate does not change.

Why does the frame-rate not change? How do I fix it?

Comment: How are you setting and how are you measuring the framerate?

Comment: I am setting the framerate using `stage.frameRate = speed;`. I'm not measuring it by outputting the value to screen or anything. It's visibly noticable that my objects are not moving as fast as they should be.

Comment: Many browsers have limits on frame rate. I know that Chrome limits it to 60fps, same as Firefox.

Comment: Is your CPU maxing out when using a browser to test? What kind of framerates are after?

Comment: The newest Flash Players are capped at a maximum of 60fps, no matter what number you use to set the framerate.  That could be one issue...  But if objects on the screen are slowing down there's nothing to be gained by changing the framerate.  It means that your swf isn't well optimized, and the player is struggling to render the assets.

Comment: @scriptocalypse OK. This is the problem. Can you create an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest Flash Players are capped at a maximum of 60fps, no matter what number you use to set the framerate. That could be one issue... But if objects on the screen are slowing down there's nothing to be gained by changing the framerate. It means that your swf isn't well optimized, and the player is struggling to render the assets.

Answer (score 1):

Set your HTML so that the Flash Object's wmode is "opaque" (or transparent if you really need to). If you don't specify it, it will interpret it as some other default parameter which gives you that drop in frame-rate performance.

Sample:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data=
 "YourFlashMovie.swf" width="640" height="480"
 id="flash_id_1" style="visibility: visible;">
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <param name="allowScale" value="never" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" /> <!-- THIS IS WHAT YOU MUST SET -->
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="scale" value="" />
  <param name="scaleMode" value="" />
  <param name="menu" value="false" />
</object>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: setting wmode to transparent tends to cause a performance hit, dropping the framerate.

Comment: as well as cause several other annoying bugs, like not being able to type an @ sign in input fields in some browsers... setting your wmode to direct (or in some cases "gpu") is a better option

Comment: Hmm, will give 'direct' a try, will update once I confirm those changes makes the framerate consistent across browsers.

Comment: So is "direct" a rendering mode that ensures that no v-sync tearing occurs in the Flash Player? It seems to keep the frame-rate a lot more stable than "opaque".

Comment: My understanding was "best practices" from adobe indicate to not set a wmode anymore, that flashplayer chooses its best option - either GPU, Direct or opaque, depending on system capacity. The only time you would directly specify is in the case of "transparent". idk. i could be wrong.

Comment: @Bosworth99, Yeah I imagine Adobe would now have the wmode automatically set to the most likely to benefit in performance. However, since which version of the Flash Player is this effective? There's that little piece of detail to take in consideration, but then again I'm not an expert in this area! Just going with what I've heard / researched in my years of AS3 experience.

Comment: @bigp. "since which version". That I do not know for certain. I believe that its FP 9.0, but I could be mistaken.